# Transpose one set of values in a row to columns values into SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Information Table which has values

```
Code Question    Score
BU   1,2,3,4     10
BI   2,3,4,5,6,7  6
```

Output

```
Code Question Score
BU   1        10
BU   2        10
BU   3        10
BU   4        10
BU   5        10
BI   2        6
BI   3        6
BI   4        6
BI   5        6
BI   6        6
BI   7        6
```

I am not not able get the output in the right format but request you to please suggest is it the write way to do because in the real time scenario the data can be in millions

Comment: [STRING_SPLIT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: It is highly unlikely that storing data like that is the "right" way.  What type of column is `Question` and how big is it? What if there is one more question that the number you have allowed for?

Comment: Select * from yourtable t cross apply string_split(t.question, ',') x